# Semantic: Trigger functions (Dimmer) after form validation passes

Tags: semantic-ui

Using Semantic-ui.

Have a form that uses Semantic built in form validation.

On form submit I want to call a dimmer.

Is there a way to trigger the dimmer after the form passes validation.

As it is now I have the dimmer connected to a onclick="dimmer()" on the submit button.

This means that the dimmer triggers even if the form is not submitting because of failed validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
onSuccess: function(event, fields) {
              dim();
              }
```

---

### example

```
$(document)
    .ready(function() {
      $('.ui.form')
        .form({
          fields: {
            trailer: {
              identifier  : 'trailer',
              rules: [
                {
                  type   : 'empty',
                  prompt : 'Please select a Trailer'
                }
              ]
            },
            movie: {
              identifier  : 'movie',
              rules: [
                {
                  type   : 'empty',
                  prompt : 'Please select a Movie'
                }            
              ]
            }
          },
              onSuccess: function(event, fields) {
              dim();
              }
        })
      ;
    })
  ;
```